# PHP: How to tell if I am debugging (eclipse) the script

Tags: php, eclipse, debugging

Is there some trick in PHP to know procedurally if the script is running under Eclipse (XDebug) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using XDebug, you aren't actually running the script *under* Eclipse. It's running wherever it would normally run (via a browser or the command line, etc), but with the XDebug extension also emitting information about the execution of the script that Eclipse can listen to.

There isn't a particularly straightforward way to test if anything is listening to the debug output, at least that I'm aware of. You can test if the XDebug extension is loaded using [`extension_loaded`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extension-loaded.php), but that doesn't tell you exactly what you need to know.

Potentially, you might be able to try and initiate a TCP connection to the debug port you've specified in Eclipse (using [`fsockopen`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fsockopen.php), or similar), which would give you a bit more information.